# Passing parameters to sed command

Tags: unix, sed

I want to extract part of the file between two tag names from a large file. for example I have a file named XXPOXPOEPO.txt and I want only the part of the file between * Blocks and * Items. How to pass these two tag names as parameters to sed command?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask].

Comment: More description needed in your question.What do you need exactly?Describe

Comment: Can you please help me? Its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you need exactly, but you could use bash variables in your `sed` command. For example:

```
$ start=2

$ seq -s ' ' 5 | sed "s/.*\($start\)/\1/"
2 3 4 5
```